# SCSS color variables that belong to an object

Tags: variables, colors, sass, naming

I am refactoring a project's SCSS to map colors to their own variable in a `_colors.scss` file.

More often than not, I am encountering the situation in which a selector has a `background-color` and `color`. So, I end up writing the following variables:

```
$cool-table-bg: $brand-primary;
$cool-table-text: $white;
```

Pretty soon I end up with many, many versions of the above.

What I want to know is, can I assign the above to an object like you would do in JavaScript? For example:

```
$cool-table: {
  bg: $brand-primary;
  text: $white;
}
```

I'd like to be able to refer to such colors as `$cool-table.bg`.

Is this possible?

Comment: The notation is not present in SCSS but if you wanna make it modular you could use placeholders. `%myCoolCSS { color: $cool-table-text; background-color: $cool-table-bg; }` and use `@extend` in every place you wanna use it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Dan Gamble suggested, I’d definitely go for SASS maps. Write yourself some tools for color handling. Something like:

```
// define globally somewhere in your setup
$COLORS = ();

// use mixin to define colors groups by e.g. element name
// example: @include color-set(cool-table, bg, #ff0000);
// or pass in a map to define multiple colors at once
// example: @include color-set(cool-table, ( bg: #ff0000, border: #00ff00));
@mixin color-set($group-name, $color-name, $color-value: false) {
  @if (type-of($color-name) == map) {
    @each $name, $value in $color-name {
      @include define-color($group-name, $name, $value);
    }
  }
  @else {
    @if(map-has-key($COLORS, $group-name)) {
      $group: map-get($COLORS, $group-name);
    }
    @else {
      $group: ();
    }
    $group: map-merge($group, ( $color-name: $color-value ));
    $COLORS: map-merge($COLORS, ( $group-name: $group )) !global;
  }
}

// access color values anywhere with this function by passing in 
// element name and color identifier
// example: $bg-color: color-get(cool-table, bg);
@function color-get($group-name, $color-name) {
  @if (map-has-key($COLORS, $group-name)) { 
    $group: map-get($COLORS, $group-name);
    @if (map-has-key($group, $color-name)) {
      @return map-get($group, $color-name);
    }
  }
  @return false;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use maps. A good write up is here:

https://www.sitepoint.com/using-sass-maps/

To see the available functions you can go [here](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/Sass/Script/Functions.html) and scroll down to map functions